# How to set multiple properties for FullCalendar in Angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to set some specific options for `FullCalendar` in Angular app, like `locale`, `themeSystem`. I found on the web that people are setting those options with `[options]` property, but it seems that for `FullCalendar` version 4 there isn't such property.

> property options is not provided by any applicable directives nor by fullcalendar element

I tried also to use api.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import { FullCalendarComponent } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import { OptionsInput } from '@fullcalendar/core/types/input-types';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;

  options: OptionsInput;

  constructor() {

  }

  calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.options = {
      locale: 'pl',
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap'
    };
    const api = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
    api.setOptions(this.options);
    api.render();
  }
}
```

```html
<full-calendar
  #calendar
  defaultView="dayGridMonth"
  [plugins]="calendarPlugins">
</full-calendar>
```

But I get this

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setOptions' of undefined

How can I set multiple options without creating for each property in class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error means this setOption is not present in this object, check your calendar reference, is it initialize properly when you sets the option, sometime calendar is in initialize phase and we are setting the values. add options in SetTimeOut with 500milisecond like this.in 500ms you calendar will initialize

```
          ngOnInit(): void {
            this.options = {
              locale: 'pl',
              themeSystem: 'bootstrap'
            };
           setTimeout(()=>{ 
    const api = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
            api.setOptions(this.options);
            api.render();
           },500);
          }
    }
```

or you can use this ngAfterViewInit

```
   ngAfterViewInit(){
     const api = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
                api.setOptions(this.options);
                api.render();
}
```

Comment: Same thing ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setOption' of undefined

Comment: @slovvic what is `calendarComponent` here ? Can you post the HTML?

Comment: this error means this  setOption is not present in this object, check your calendar reference, is it initialize properly when you sets the option, sometime  calendar is in initialize phase and we are setting the values.   add options in SetTimeOut with 500milisecond then try this.

Comment: calendarComponent its means your getting reference of html element . like you have to add tag like this 
 <full-calendar
      #calendar
      defaultView="dayGridMonth"
      [header]="{
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
      }"
      [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
      [weekends]="calendarWeekends"
      [events]="calendarEvents"
      (dateClick)="handleDateClick($event)"
    ></full-calendar>

Comment: @ShahidIslam You were right. When I set the options in `ngAfterViewInit()` method, options were applied.

Comment: @ShahidIslam sure, edit your answer to proper one :)